# create python file or files to execute file like file.exe

Tags: python

I have created one python file, and converted that to file.exe. This file is executing correctly in Windows 8.1 64-bit and Win server 2012, but  it does not run in Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit.

I see errors like "not compatible ... file.exe in win"> ,
how to create a file.exe compatible for all OS versions (like win7, win8 , 8.1 , 10)?

[I used pyinstaller and other tools for my Gui program.]

Comment: Did you try py2exe (https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)?

Comment: yes,  but dont work correct in os lower vesions like win7(32,64)

Comment: Did you manage to make your Python file run without problem on win7 before converting it to .exe? Also, I see in your question you mention you converted to "flie.exe", but the error says: "file.exe". Finally, did you check "file.exe" is somewhere Windows can find it easily (look for the environment variable %PATH% into Control Panel --> System --> Advanced --> Environment Variables

Comment: Did you check this out https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2149 ?

Comment: Did you manage to make your Python file run without problem on win7 before converting it to .exe? No beacuse win 7 (I had executed in 3 computer with win 7) had not python ide. i have try to run file.exe in win7-32 or win7 -64، whereas i can run file.exe in win8.1 or winServer2012.
i use pyinstaller to convert python file to exe file.